# Two questions about charge between capacitor plates

Tags: voltage, batteries, capacitor, electromagnetism

Let's say that we have capacitor with two identical plates - but one of them (let's call it plate A) is 50% of the size. Let's put a current through this capacitor so that there is some voltage V.

Questions:

1. Will the electrical charge between those two plates be the same?
2. Will electromagnetic current between those two plates be the same?

Comment: What is electromagnetic current?

Comment: @haneefmubarak: strenght of electromagnetic field? I am not sure how to translate this from my native language.

Comment: I think by number one you mean the total energy stored in the capacitor, and by number two you mean the current that will flow between the two plates if a voltage is applied. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I think that what ojek means is "displacement current" (Maxwell's extension of Ampere's law).

Comment: In what sense are two different-sized plates "identical"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you would want to have the plates different areas escapes me but here goes.

[image]

The charge on the plates will be the same.

The electric field between the plates will essentially follow the geometry as the charge on the smaller and larger plate will be evenly spread over its surface forming equipotentials parallel to the plates.

Comment: And since there will be higher "density of charge" on the smaller plate (since charge on both plates remains the same), wouldn't that affect strength of it's electric field?

Comment: @ojek - No - the total charge (Q) on the plate determines the voltage (V = Q/C), not the charge density. The electric field is determined by this voltage and the distance between the plates (V/d).

Answer (score 2):

> Will the electrical charge between those two plates be the same?

If you're asking if the magnitude of electric charge on each is equal then I think the answer must be yes.  You're charging the capacitor with a current.  Let's assume for simplicity the current is some constant I during some time T.  Then, in T seconds, Q = IT Coulombs of charge is placed on one plate and removed from the other.  This is just an application of KCL.

> Will electromagnetic current between those two plates be the same?

If, by electromagnetic current, you mean displacement current, isn't there just *one* current between the plates?  I don't understand what you're trying to ask here.